# How to copy a message from COPYDATASTRUCT in C?

Tags: c

my c# coding to send the message to WM_COPYDATA

```
public static bool SendArgs(IntPtr targetHWnd, string args)
        {
            Win32.CopyDataStruct cds = new Win32.CopyDataStruct();
            try
            {
                cds.cbData = (args.Length + 1) * 2;
                cds.lpData = Win32.LocalAlloc(0x40, cds.cbData);
                Marshal.Copy(args.ToCharArray(), 0, cds.lpData, args.Length);
                cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1;
                Win32.SendMessage(targetHWnd, Win32.WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
            }
            finally
            {
                cds.Dispose();
            }

            return true;
        }
```

my c code to receive message is

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message,
                WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message) {
case WM_COPYDATA:
          {

COPYDATASTRUCT* copy_data = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)(lParam);

            const char* str = (const char* )(copy_data->lpData);
            /* Also fixed the parameter list for "%.*s" */
    printf("Message (%u): %.*s\n", copy_data->dwData, (int)copy_data->cbData, str);
}
}
}
```

using the above code i retrieve the first character of the message, not all the content

Comment: What goes wrong? Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it give the wrong output?

Comment: Just substitute a `C`-style cast for the `reinterpret_cast`.  They essentially mean the same thing anyway.

Comment: @Chad Are you insinuating that C++ casts don't work?

Comment: Unless you actually show us how the struct is populated on the other side of the interface, we cannot help. And it always helps if you tell us how things fail rather than making us guess.

Comment: Only if he really wants to "achieve this in C", as in using a pure `C` compiler.  They work (and are appropriate for this in `C++`).

Comment: Oh, I see! Perhaps that's the problem. Perhaps it's just a compiler error from a C compiler.

Comment: Are you **sure** that `copy_data.lpData` points to a NULL-terminated string? Typically, all the API will guarantee (provided the sender called it correctly) is that `copy_data->lpData` will point to a memory block that is `copy_data->cbData` bytes long. Those bytes can be **anything** at all. Also, note, that in your code you do: `copy_data.lpData` which is wrong and won't compiler since `copy_data` is a pointer. You need `copy_data->lpData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
if (message == WM_COPYDATA)
{
    COPYDATASTRUCT* copy_data = (COPYDATASTRUCT)(lparam);

    const char* str = (const char*)(copy_data->lpData);

    /* Also fixed the parameter list for "%.*s" */
    printf("Message (%u): %.*s\n", copy_data->dwData, (int)copy_data->cbData, str);
}
```

Of course printing `copy_data->lpData` as a string will only make sense if it really is string data.

Comment: Also consider that `copy_data->lpData` can be NULL (if that's what the caller passed in originally, which is perfectly valid).

Comment: Indeed. Otherwise you've got a trivial buffer overrun exploit on your hands.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it works fine but it retrieves the first character of the string it doesn't retrieve the entire string how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> I retrieve the first character of the message, not all the content.

This indicates that the string is encoded as UTF-16 and it can be seen from the C# code that generates the message that the data you send is UTF-16 encoded.

On the other hand, your C code treats it as being 8 bit ANSI encoded. And that's why the C code fails to read it correctly. If your C code treats it as UTF-16 then you'll get all the content.

You must not assume that the string is null-terminated and should use `cbData` to avoid buffer overruns.

So you can change your C code to be like so:

```
COPYDATASTRUCT* cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)lParam;
int len = (cds->cbData/2)-1;
printf("Message (%u): %.*S\n", cds->dwData, len, cds->lpData);
```

Note that `%.*S` will treat the input as a UTF-16 encoded string, and will print no more than `len` characters.

I'm also assuming that you are using Microsoft's tools, because the `S` format type is a non-standard Microsoft special. If you want to be portable then there are ways to do that, but I'm not sure you are quite ready to tackle that issue.

Comment: Actually i am sending a message from c# application to c application, i dont know how to  Cast the pointer to wchar_t*. can you provide code sample

Comment: I'm not providing code until you fix your question. You say the language is C, but clearly it is C++. And you don't give any details in the question of how it fails. You also don't show the C# code. So, I'll go further once you do so. You've already managed to cast to char*, see if you can guess how to cast to wchar_t*. I'm sure my answer is accurate and I'm sorry you don't find it helpful.

Comment: now i edited my question. i provide the entire C# as well as c code. provide me a solution.

Comment: Why did you accept the other answer? Anyway, you need: const wchar_t* str = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(copy_ data.lpData);  And I still can't tell what language you are using. You say C, but it seems to be C++. Which is it?

Comment: once again i edited my question kindly check it and provide the solution

Comment: You already accepted the other answer. I'm not sure why you did that. Anyway, since you are clearly struggling a little, I've edited my answer to give code, as well as the explanation of the problem.

Comment: And now you've gone quiet. You ask a lot, but give little in return.

Comment: Why did you accept the other answer when it doesn't help? And do nothing with my answer which is correct?